# How to get blob URL using Logic App Standard

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-logic-app-standard

How to get the blob URL from Azure Blob Storage?

The trigger is when a blob is added or modified. The blob content could be read and I was very happy as I could insert the content into an Azure Table property, so using PK and RK the file content would be quickly retrieved.

However with larger blobs it did not work due to 32k max size for a property. The approach to overcome this limitation seems to be to save the URL blob into the property but for my life I cannot figure it out how (tried almost all actions, even those that did not make sense, perhaps the url was somewhere in the output)

Answer (score 3):

As your trigger already watches a specific Storage Account, why dont you simple concat the base URL (`https://"StorageAccountName".blob.core.windows.net`) with the "File Path"-Parameter of the Connector?
As far as i know there is no connector (yet) that gives you that information ..

Comment: thank you, tried your suggestion but it didn't work for my purpose as the storage is not public. Anyway, this gave me an idea to use "Create SAS URI by path (V2)" as I'd remembered seeing it ... and it worked :). I got the desired result but with Logic App Consumption, will have to test it for Standard as well (hopefully they have parity in functionality) @Tobi

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
one drive wont allow share a video link. it shares a office 365 link
i recommend using blob storage for connection.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection